# Array of prime numbers doesn't print out contents correctly

Tags: java, arrays

I have some problems with an array in java. I try to use thread and add prime numbers in an array but it doesn't work. I want b[c] to store all of the prime number from firstnumber to secondnumber.

```
public class btl {
public static boolean IsPrime(int n) {

    if (n < 2) {
        return false;
    }

    int squareRoot = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
    for (int i = 2; i <= squareRoot; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}




public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int first = 0;
    int second = 0;
    try {
        System.out.println("Input First Number");
     first = scanIn.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input Second Number");
        second= scanIn.nextInt();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something wrong!");
    }
    int x = first;
    int y = second;
    int a;
    int[] b = new int[y];

    Thread threadA = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {     
            int c=0;
            for(int i=x; i<y; i++)
            {   
                if(IsPrime(i)) {
                    b[c] = i;
                    c++;
                    System.out.println(b[c]);

                }

            }
        }
    });
    threadA.start();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Put the text in your question.

Comment: It's never enough to say " but It isn't work. " Say what it does, and how it differs from what you expect/want.

Comment: You print `b[c]` right after you increment `c`. So you always print zero. You're printing the element *after* the one you just assigned to.

Comment: I added a little bit of code that would fix your issue below. If it works, could you please accept it by clicking on the Gray check mark next to it, making it green?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that you append c first, and only later print out b[c], which is still a blank cell in the array. Try:

```
for(int i=x; i<y; i++) {   
        if(IsPrime(i)) {
            b[c] = i;
            System.out.println(b[c]);
            c++;
       }
 }
```

By the way, when you define the array b - you don't need all of y cells. It's a little more cost efficient to declare:

```
int[] b = new int[y-x];
```

Instead.

Comment: Brilliant @NgoHoang. Could you please click on the gray check mark next to my answer, making it green?

Comment: I have checked it. Sorry I just started taking part in stackoverflow so I did not know that. Forgive me

Comment: No problem. I truly appreciate you coming back! Welcome to SO.